# guarantee consistency of data with more transactions

Tags: html, indexeddb, web-sql

I'm writing a webapp that needs a database.

IndexedDB and websql transactions needs to be short and I read that it's better to get all data from the server and then open a transaction and write all to be sure to be consistent.

My problem is that I need to get a lot of data and I cannot keep them in memory(especially in mobile browsers). For this reason it is better to read a chunk and write a chunk, in this way the memory consuption is a lot lower. Every chunk is written by a different transaction(they are short and they are autocommitted).Obiouvsly in this way I cannot guarantee consistency.
What are the best practices for this scenario? Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a trade off between shorter transaction for consistency and longer transaction for performance.

In my library (YDN-DB), i encourage to use separate [transaction thread](http://dev.yathit.com/api-reference/ydn-db/storage.html#branch) for populating (parallel, multi-request), updating (serial, atomic) and querying (parallel, single).